# Yii Property "CUploadedFile.maxWidth" is not defined

Tags: yii

```
$uploadedFile=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image1');
$uploadedFile->maxWidth = 400;
$uploadedFile->maxHeight = 300;
```

I follow the example in [here](http://pastebin.com/BSAN20re). But I get the error saying that "Property "CUploadedFile.maxWidth" is not defined."

Is it my CUploadFile.php is not updated?

Comment: set `image` instead `image1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That pastebin source doesn't tell the whole story since it does not show where maxWidth is defined.
CUploadedfile http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile does not have a property maxWidth.

Instead of using the pastebin how about trying this extension that will do what it appears you are trying to do: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/euploadedimage/